# Show middle slide of SWIPER JS API, when page refreshes

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

By using **SWIPER JS** API I created an about us page that contains the details of our team. This is a slider actually, and this slider contains five slides and I want the third slide to be shown in the center and the two on the right side and two on left but by default first is shown remaining are below it.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/swiper.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
    <script src="../js/swiper.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="../js/js.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <title>About us</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav class="container-fluid navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light border-bottom border-secondary">
              <a class="navbar-brand p-0" href="home.html"><img  src="../img/bloodbucketLogo.png" width="150" height="65" class="mr-5"></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav" style="margin: auto" id="menuBar">
                          <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                          </li>

                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="aboutUS.html">About us</a>
                          </li>

                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="faqs.html">FAQ's</a>
                          </li>

                          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                              Articles
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">When to donate blood?</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Blood diseases</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Benefits of donating blood?</a>
                            </div>
                          </li>

                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="contactUs.html">Contact us</a>
                          </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="login.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-1">&nbsp;Login &nbsp;</button></a>
                        <a href="signUp.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Sign up</button></a>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </nav>
        
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="container-fluid ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h1 style="font-family: Oxanium;" class="mt-2">Our Team</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container-fluid" id="aboutUs">
            <div class="row team">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center" title="Swipe right!">
                    <div class="swiper-container">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                          <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="card bg-light" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img class="" src="../img/donarsAvatars/4.png" style="margin-top: -25px;" width="95" height="85" alt="Card image cap">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title text-center">Ehtisham Ul Haq</h5>
                                  <h6 class="text-primary text-center">Founder</h6> 
                                  <hr>

                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Java Desktop Developer <i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Full Stack Web Developer(PHP Laravel) </p>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Mobile Application Developer(Android) <i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                                
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="card-body text-center">
                                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a> 
                                </div>
                                    
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="card bg-light" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img class="" src="../img/donarsAvatars/1.png" style="margin-top: -25px;" width="95" height="85" alt="Card image cap">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title text-center">Mohammad Moazam</h5>
                                  <h6 class="text-primary text-center">Co-Founder</h6> 
                                  <hr>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Java Desktop Developer <i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Full Stack Web Developer(PHP Laravel) </p>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Mobile Application Developer(Android) <i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                                
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="card-body text-center">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a> 
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="card bg-light" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img class=""  src="../img/donarsAvatars/1.png" style="margin-top: -25px;" width="95" height="85" alt="Card image cap">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title text-center">Abdul Rab</h5>
                                  <h6 class="text-primary text-center">Co-Founder</h6> 
                                  <hr>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Java Desktop Developer <i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Full Stack Web Developer(PHP Laravel) </p>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Mobile Application Developer(Android) <i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                                
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="card-body text-center">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a> 
                                </div>
                                
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="card bg-light" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img class=""  src="../img/donarsAvatars/4.png" style="margin-top: -25px;" width="95" height="85" alt="Card image cap">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title text-center">Hamza Muzaffar</h5>
                                  <h6 class="text-primary text-center">Co-Founder</h6> 
                                  <hr>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Java Desktop Developer <i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Full Stack Web Developer(PHP Laravel) </p>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Mobile Application Developer(Android) <i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                                
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="card-body text-center">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a> 
                                </div>
                                
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="card bg-light" style="width: 18rem;">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img class="" src="../img/donarsAvatars/4.png" style="margin-top: -25px;" width="95" height="85" alt="Card image cap">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title text-center">Khalil Ahmed</h5>
                                  <h6 class="text-primary text-center">Co-Founder</h6> 
                                  <hr>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Java Desktop Developer <i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Full Stack Web Developer(PHP Laravel) </p>
                                  <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 12px;">Mobile Application Developer(Android) <i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
                                
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="card-body text-center">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a> |
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a> 
                                </div>
                            
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer class="container-fluid bg">
        <div class="row bg">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="fixed-bottom border-top border-dark bg">
                    <div class="bg"> 
                        <div class="mr-4 text-center bg">
                            <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i> |
                            <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> |
                            <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> |
                            <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i> |
                            <i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**API LINK**

https://swiperjs.com/demos/240-effect-coverflow.html

****The way it shows right now****
[image: Current Display]

***But, I want to look like this when page reloads***
[image]

> **IF NEED any thing or have any confusion please ask, but help me to solve this.**

Comment: You could set the `initialSlide` parameter of the swiper instance to `2` to allow the slider to start at the third slide.

Comment: How can be this done? can you be more specific?

Comment: Somewhere in your JS you are (assuming this is is true) creating an instance of a swiper slider. Something like `var mySwiper = new Swiper();`. The `new Swiper()` part can take an options object in which you can set certain options, like the `initialSlide`. That's the thing you should modify. But I can help you better if you include the JavaScript in which you call swiper.

Comment: Great, feel free to leave a self-answer below with the code you've modified so that others with the same question might be helped. As a finishing touch add the original JavaScript to the question so the difference between question and answer is obvious to see. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

> Before

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    effect: 'coverflow',
    grabCursor: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    coverflowEffect: {
      rotate: 50,
      stretch: 0,
      depth: 300,
      modifier: 1,
      slideShadows : false,
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
  });
```

> After

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    effect: 'coverflow',
    grabCursor: true,
    initialSlide:2,   //Added this
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    coverflowEffect: {
      rotate: 50,
      stretch: 0,
      depth: 300,
      modifier: 1,
      slideShadows : false,
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
  });
```